# How to implement the Factory project pattern in VBA?

Tags: vba, factory

I would like to know if it is possible to apply to the Factory Method project pattern within the limitations of VBA. If it is possible, would you have an example?

Comment: You need to read some discussions on classes in VBA, specifically about Factories. See the [Rubberduck Blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/01/11/oop-in-vba-immutability-the-factory-pattern/) and [these ramblings](https://hammondmason.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/object-oriented-vba-design-patterns-simple-factory/)

Comment: @PeterT beat me to it! :D

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the default module create:

modEnumPizza

```
Public Enum enumTypePizza

    Pepperoni
    Cheese

End Enum
```

modMain

```
Sub Main()

    Dim objPizza As IPizza
    Dim objFactory As Factory

    Set objFactory = New Factory

    Set objPizza = objFactory.CreatingPizza(Cheese, "Cheese Pizza", "mozzarella, oregano, olive, simple sauce", 25.99)

    Debug.Print "Name: " & objPizza.getName
    Debug.Print "Ingredients: " & objPizza.getIngredients
    Debug.Print "Price: " & objPizza.getPrice

    Set objPizza = objFactory.CreatingPizza(Pepperoni, "Pepperoni Pizza",     "Calabresa, onion, olive, oregano", 30.99)

    Debug.Print "Name: " & objPizza.getName
    Debug.Print "Ingredients: " & objPizza.getIngredients
    Debug.Print "Price: " & objPizza.getPrice

End Sub
```

In the class module create:

IPizza

```
Sub create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double): End Sub
Property Get getName() As String: End Property
Property Get getIngredients() As String: End Property
Property Get getPrice() As Long: End Property
```

clsCheese

```
Implements IPizza
Implements ICreate

Private Type TType
    name As String
    ingredients As String
    price As Double    
End Type

Private this As TType

Private Sub IPizza_create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double)

    With this
        .name = name
        .ingredients = ingredients
        .price = price
    End With

End Sub

Private Property Get IPizza_getIngredients() As String
    IPizza_getIngredients = this.ingredients
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getName() As String
    IPizza_getName = this.name
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getPrice() As Long
    IPizza_getPrice = this.price
End Property
```

clsPepperoni

```
Implements IPizza

Private Type TType
    name As String
    ingredients As String
    price As Double    
End Type

Private this As TType

Private Sub IPizza_create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double)

    With this
        .name = name
        .ingredients = ingredients
        .price = price
    End With

End Sub

Private Property Get IPizza_getIngredients() As String
    IPizza_getIngredients = this.ingredients
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getName() As String
    IPizza_getName = this.name
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getPrice() As Long
    IPizza_getPrice = this.price
End Property
```

Factory

```
Function CreatingPizza(ByVal enumPizza As enumTypePizza, ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza

    Dim objPizza As IPizza

    If enumPizza = Cheese Then

        Set objPizza = New clsCheese

    ElseIf enumPizza = Pepperoni Then

        Set objPizza = New clsPepperoni

    End If

    objPizza.create name, ingredients, price

    Set CreatingPizza = objPizza

End Function
```

For details on the Factory default, you can refer to the "Use Head - Design Patterns" book.

Run Main from the modMain module and see the Verification window (CTRL + G).

Note that in the 'Factory' class we have the 'CreatingPizza' function, where we select the type of pizza being created, by means of Enum type (enumPizza). If we have dozens of different pizzas to create we will have dozens of IF's. If we have to get flavors from the module modEnumPizza, we will have to change 'CreatingPizza'.

[image]

In addition, the 'create' method is visible in IntelliSense. If this and fact that we have many IFs does not please you, one solution, which is what I use is this:

Create an interface responsible for the 'create' method:

ICreateCheese

```
Function create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza: End Function
```

ICreatePepperoni

```
Function create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza: End Function
```

Now remove the 'crete' method from IPizza:

IPizza

```
Property Get getName() As String: End Property
Property Get getIngredients() As String: End Property
Property Get getPrice() As Long: End Property
```

Now clsChesse and clsPepperoni respectively implement ICreateChesse and ICreatePepperoni.

clsCheese

```
Implements IPizza
Implements ICreateChesse

Private Type TType
    name As String
    ingredients As String
    price As Double

End Type

Private this As TType

Private Function ICreateChesse_create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza

    With this
        .name = name
        .ingredients = ingredients
        .price = price
    End With

    Set ICreateChesse_create = Me

End Function

Private Property Get IPizza_getIngredients() As String
    IPizza_getIngredients = this.ingredients
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getName() As String
    IPizza_getName = this.name
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getPrice() As Long
    IPizza_getPrice = this.price
End Property
```

clsPepperoni

```
Implements IPizza
Implements ICreatePepperoni

Private Type TType
    name As String
    ingredients As String
    price As Double

End Type

Private this As TType

Private Function ICreatePepperoni_create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza

    With this
        .name = name
        .ingredients = ingredients
        .price = price
    End With

    Set ICreatePepperoni_create = Me

End Function

Private Property Get IPizza_getIngredients() As String
    IPizza_getIngredients = this.ingredients
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getName() As String
    IPizza_getName = this.name
End Property

Private Property Get IPizza_getPrice() As Long
    IPizza_getPrice = this.price
End Property
```

Factory

```
Implements ICreateChesse
Implements ICreatePepperoni

Private Type TType
    'Could be a Dictionary References => Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    objCollection As Collection
    objPizza As IPizza

End Type

Private this As TType

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim objInterfaceChesse As ICreateChesse
    Dim objInterfacePepperoni As ICreatePepperoni

    Set objInterfaceChesse = Me
    Set objInterfacePepperoni = Me

    Set this.objCollection = New Collection


    'We now have a collection of instance variables pointing to ICreateChesse_create and
    'ICreatePepperoni_create
    With this.objCollection

        .Add objInterfaceChesse, CStr(enumTypePizza.Cheese)
        .Add objInterfacePepperoni, CStr(enumTypePizza.Pepperoni)

    End With


End Sub


Function CreatingPizza(ByVal enumPizza As enumTypePizza, ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza

    Dim objInterface As Object

                       'we return the corresponding instance variable
    Set objInterface = this.objCollection(CStr(enumPizza))

                        'method call by late binding
    Set CreatingPizza = objInterface.create(name, ingredients, price)

End Function


Private Function ICreateChesse_create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza

    Dim objPizza As clsCheese
    Dim objInterfaceChesse As ICreateChesse

    'We create an instance of clsPizza
    Set objPizza = New clsCheese

    'We point to the interface address in clsChesse
    Set objInterfaceChesse = objPizza

    'I call the 'create' method of the instance of clsPizza, which returns the interface I`Pizza
    Set ICreateChesse_create = objInterfaceChesse.create(name, ingredients, price)

    Set objPizza = Nothing
    Set objInterfaceChesse = Nothing

End Function

Private Function ICreatePepperoni_create(ByVal name As String, ByVal ingredients As String, ByVal price As Double) As IPizza

    Dim objPizza As clsPepperoni
    Dim objInterfacePepperoni As ICreatePepperoni

    Set objPizza = New clsPepperoni

    Set objInterfacePepperoni = objPizza

    Set ICreatePepperoni_create = objInterfacePepperoni.create(name, ingredients, price)

    Set objPizza = Nothing
    Set objInterfacePepperoni = Nothing

End Function
```

ModMain does not change.

And the project looks like this:

[image]

Another alternative that avoids the use of a Factory class data structure would be this:
Create an interface called ISelectCreator, where we can return by intelliSense which interface to use: ICreateChesse or ICreatePepperoni.

With this we can exclude the module modEnumPizza. In addition, the modMain module will also be modified, as the Factory class will change.

Here's the new refactoring in the Factory class and the creation of the ISelectCreator interface:

[image]

ISelectCreator

```
Property Get getCreateChesse() As ICreateChesse: End Property
Property Get getCreatePepperoni() As ICreatePepperoni: End Property
```

Factory

```
Implements ISelectCreator

Function CreatingPizza() As ISelectCreator

    'with this intelliSense will show: getCreateChesse and getCreatePepperoni
    Set CreatingPizza = Me

End Function

Private Property Get ISelectCreator_getCreateChesse() As ICreateChesse

    Dim objPizza As clsCheese

    Set objPizza = New clsCheese

    Set ISelectCreator_getCreateChesse = objPizza

End Property

Private Property Get ISelectCreator_getCreatePepperoni() As ICreatePepperoni

    Dim objPizza As clsPepperoni

    Set objPizza = New clsPepperoni

    Set ISelectCreator_getCreatePepperoni = objPizza

End Property
```

The Factory class is much simpler.

modMain: Main

```
Sub Main()

    Dim objPizza As IPizza
    Dim objFactory As Factory

    Set objFactory = New Factory

    Set objPizza = objFactory.CreatingPizza.getCreateChesse.create("Cheese Pizza", "mozzarella, oregano, olive, simple sauce", 25.99)

    Debug.Print "Name: " & objPizza.getName
    Debug.Print "Ingredients: " & objPizza.getIngredients
    Debug.Print "Price: " & objPizza.getPrice

    Set objPizza = objFactory.CreatingPizza.getCreatePepperoni.create("Pepperoni     Pizza", "Calabresa, onion, olive, oregano", 30.99)

    Debug.Print "Name: " & objPizza.getName
    Debug.Print "Ingredients: " & objPizza.getIngredients
    Debug.Print "Price: " & objPizza.getPrice

End Sub
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

Actually this is the way I currently use it. So that's it, Factory Method is possible yes.